# RitaWordnet API has no support for retrieving sense number?

Tags: java, perl, wordnet

I'm comparing some senses with RitaWordNet and using SenseRelate::AllWords to word sense disambiguate them, but I'm in trouble. I can't figure out how to compare the output from RitaWordnet with AllWords script.

Rita give me senseid, name, description, pos/bestPos (adjective, verb, noun etc) but not sense number (#1,#2,#3..) The output I I get is like this:

```
"user","n", "someone who use something..".
```

::AllWords can't retrieve description, but (wsd.pl) give me

```
name#pos#sensenumber ("User#n#1").
```

Which was what I was hoping for actually, but then I realized that Rita doesn't support sense numbers (strangely). 
So now I'm a little stuck on how to compare them, how to determine if they are the same sense. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that WordNet returns a sorted list based on nouns, verbs etc.

```
Example: "story"
Noun: narrative, narration, story, tale #1
Noun: story #2
Noun: floor, level, storey, story #3
```

So now I can simply add sense number 1, 2 and 3 to the first three nouns (and the rest will continune of course). Then I can compare this with user#n#1 from the word sense disambiguation. The creators of RitaWordNet responded that they would like to implement the sense number in their api, but they don't have an upcoming relase for a new version so this may take a while.